# How to create dynamic controls using html helper in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-helper

Need : I have a div with dropdown using htmlhelper, and a button.
the button is used to take clone of the div. 
when user click the button the jquery create the clone of the div.

DIV :

```
  <div id="#step-1" class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Material</label>
       <div id="cbx-booking-material" class="col-md-9">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BookingMatrialID, Model.BookingMaterialList,"Selcct a Material..", new { @id = "we", @class = "form-control select" })
  </div>
```

JQuery :

```
 $("#id").clone().prependTo('#step-1');
```

ISSUE : The button clicks perfectly, div clone create also fine. but the dropdown not able to select a option.its always display the default text "select a material.."

Why this is happens?
What is the solution for that?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by _the dropdown not able to select a option_. But your generating invalid html when you clone the elements because of duplicate `id` attributes (the `id` attributes in both `<div>` and the `<select>`). Remove the `id` and use class names instead - for the `DropDownListFor()` method, use `new { @id = "" }`.

Comment: But its somewhat unclear what would be the point of this. You generating dropdoanlists with duplicate `name` attributes so only the value of the first dropdown will be bound to your model anyway (all the others will be ignored)